# Substitution question $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\ne\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Using the substitution $x=\dfrac{1}{t}$ we get 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

But the integrals are not equal. Why exactly does this substitution not work?

Comment: Note to people who think a sufficient answer is $x=0$ on the interval so you can't substitute $x=1/t$:

Consider $I=\int_{-1}^{1}x\,dx=0$

Substituting $u=1/x$ we get $I\int_{-1}^{1}=-\frac{1}{u^3}\,du=0$

So it works in this case. My question is why exactly it doesn't work in the specific case above.

Comment: Integration by substitution requires the function we substitute to be continuously differentiable.Clearly $1/x$ doesn't satisfy this as the interval contains 0.

Comment: @LTS Hey LTS, I'm pinging you because I typed up an answer to your newly deleted question, and I didn't want it to go completely to waste :). So, here it is:

Hint: Let 
$$a_n=\prod\limits_{k=n}^\infty c$$
Now for some fixed $\epsilon>0$, you can prove $a_n<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2^n}$. Now once you have this bound, taking 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$

Gives the result that analysis always strives for.

Answer (score 3):

Because the extremes of integration are wrong. $$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{0}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx =\int_{-1}^{-\infty}-\frac{1}{t^2}f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt+\int_{+\infty}^{1}-\frac{1}{t^2}f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt=-\int_{-\infty}^{-1}-\frac{1}{t^2}f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt-\int_{1}^{+\infty}-\frac{1}{t^2}f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt$$

Comment: Try to think what happens if you brake the integral in $\int_{-1}^{0}+\int_{0}^{1}$

Comment: ah.. thank you, that works